# Does taking an n-th root of a negative number lead to contradictions?

Tags: roots, radicals

$(-3)^3 = -27$. $f(x) = x^3$ is a bijective function, $g(x) = \sqrt[3]x$ is defined for all values of $x$. But my maths teacher said, that $\sqrt[n]a = b \iff b^n = a, a\geq0$. She said that allowing the notation e.g. $-3 =\sqrt[3]{-27}$ leads to contradictions, and the she went and did this:

$$-3 = \sqrt[3]{-27} = (-27)^\frac {1}{3} = (-27)^\frac {2}{6} = \sqrt[6]{(-27)^2} = \sqrt[6]{27^2} = 27^\frac{2}{6} = 27^\frac{1}{3}=\sqrt[3]{27}=3$$

Is there a mistake in the “proof”, or is an $\sqrt[n]a$ really only defined for $a\geq 0$?

I do know that $(-3)^3 = -27$ and all that. I am aware of real and complex roots, and of the attributes of even and odd orders of roots and powers. I searched online and found no mention of $\sqrt[n]a$ only being defined for $a\geq0$.

I am asking whether the DEFINITION of the $n$-th root allows us to take the root of a negative number (I presume it does), and if so, then how can I prove the wrongness of the "proof" above?

Comment: It's not the definition that causes problems, it's the manipulation of exponents willy-nilly that does.

Answer (score 1):

Negative numbers raised to rational exponents can indeed cause issues.

A safe definition is that

$$(-x)^{p/q}$$ is allowed when the fraction is *irreducible* and has an odd denominator. In that case, the result is positive or negative depending on the parity of the numerator.

Using that definition,

$$(-27)^{2/6}$$ *must* be rewritten

$$(-27)^{1/3}$$ which is $-3$.

Comment: I am sure that your definition is safe and mathematically sound. Still, it has peculiar properties. For example $(-27)$ raised to the power $2/3$ equals $9$, but raised to the power $20000001/30000001$ gives approximately $-9$.

Comment: @M.Wind: this is exactly why real exponents are ruled out: the parities couldn't be determined. This rule is the last support we can provide to negative bases.

Comment: I agree !!! It also shows that it is in fact preferable to introduce complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You do have to be careful manipulating rational exponents and negative bases. You can't have $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$ true in general; there must be some restrictions, either to the base or to the exponents, or to whether you can apply the rule. Your teacher thinks the restriction should be in the base (the base should be non-negative). As I read you, you think it should be a combination (as long as you don't have both negative base and exponent with even denominator, it's fine). Both approaches solve the problem.